# Is there a way to retrieve the documents in a Firestore collection and store them as a list<user-defined class>?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Title is self-explanatory. Some sample code would be appreciated.

If it is possible, is there a way to extract all documents in a collection corresponding to the value of a particular field in the documents (i.e. filter implementation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can use `StreamBuilder`. For example :

```
                StreamBuilder(
                  stream: Firestore.instance
                           .collection("yourCollection")
                           .where("query", isEqualTo: "something"),
                           .snapshots();
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Center(
                        child: Text("Error fetching posts ${snapshot.error}"),
                      );
                    }
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      List<UserDefinedModel> list = snapshot.data.documents;

                      // other code...
                      // return Widget
                    }
                  }
               );
```